# struct in python

Tags: python

I have been unable to understand the working of pack in struct in python.

For example I need to make 4 bytes of data together into one struct.
Suppose the first byte has the value 4 in it while the second has 5 and then 6 and last 7.
so i make it as

```
a = chr(4 & 0x0f)
b = chr(5 & 0x0f)
c = chr(6 & 0x0f)
d = chr(7 & 0x0f)
```

Now I need to pack them into a single structure using pack. How should i do it ?

I would also request to please explain in some detail as I need this not for just above example only and i need to understand how to do it.....

Here's the link to it [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that with this

```
import struct
struct.pack('4B', 4, 6, 7, 8,)
```

`struct` is some kind of printf for building bytes structures is very handy
when you are dealing with a low-level protocol, you can use the references of the 
module for the string formating, take a look at this wol script
that I wrote, check out [this file](https://github.com/cyraxjoe/awake/blob/master/src/awake/wol.py) 
and how it use the struct module to build the WOL packet.

Comment: Does 4B mean that it should be stored as 4 unsigned integer and is it equal to 'BBBB' in the same ???